# What is the FTP Command for deleting multiple files as once?

Tags: ftp

I'm trying to run this command via FTP in order to delete some files I have stored in a folder in my website:

```
DEL *.csv
```

However this doesn't work and I don't know why. However if I try to delete every single file this works:

```
DEL file.csv (works)
```

How could I do in order to solve this issue?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you're using the Windows command-line ftp client, then you will need to use `mdelete` to delete multiple files, as `delete` will only delete a single file.

Edit: Answering the additional questions in the comments.

If you want to put these commands in a file so that you can perform them as some kind of batch process, you could create a text file and put the commands in sequence there:

```
prompt
mdel *
quit
```

Then you could run this as a single step with the `-s` parameter.

Comment: As a side note, the MS command-line client also supports mput for putting multiple files up at a time (mput *.dll).

Comment: Thanks, it works fine!!! However if I write MDEL *.csv it asks the confirmation, I would do this automatically without confirmation, how could I do this?

Comment: I've not tested it, but you might try putting the `mdel` command (and possibly the "yes" response that `mdel` wants) inside a text file and then using the `-s` option to load the ftp commands from the file.

Comment: Thanks but where should I put the yes response?

Comment: use `prompt` to switch interactive mode off before using `mdel`

Comment: So should I write something like "prompt mdel *.csv" ?

Comment: If you're working with ftp interactively, then the `prompt` and `mdel` commands would be entered separately.

Comment: It is worth noting that MDEL is not a valid FTP command (as per RFC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_commands) so some FTP servers, notably the latest FileZilla Server will not accept it

Answer (score 3):

To use mdelete use the syntax below to automate the process

At the FTP> use the "prompt" command to disable interaction (mode off)

Type this command:

- FTP> mdelete [directory] *.extenstion |yes

For example, mdelete standard *.jpg |yes

Comment: mdelete with prompts ftw.

Answer (score 1):

With Windows 7:

The existing answer will work only partially. To delete more files at once without confirmation from the server we must connect to the server with the command:

```
ftp -i yourwebsite
```

So after you connect with that command, you can use `mdelete` at the FTP prompt:

```
mdelete *.html
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example for an inline multidelete ftp script, added bonus an aritmetic YYYYMM variable. Use `prompt` to disable an interactive prompt query.

```
#!/bin/sh
## Delete files from FTP server

HOST=11.22.33.44
USER=myuser
PWD="mypwd"

YM=$(date +'%Y%m')
YM=$(( $YM-3 ))
echo YearMonth $YM

ftp -p -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PWD
prompt
mdel prefix${YM}*.zip
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```